# How to handle NoneType in any() statement?

Tags: python, arrays, any

I have an `any()` statement in python, and some of the elements in `memo_field` array are `None`.

```
any(memo_field[1][0] in row[9] for memo_field in memo_fields)
```

What is the best way to handle those `NoneType` elements in the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement must be better than above.

```
any(memo_field[1][0] in row[9] for memo_field in memo_fields if memo_field is not None)
```

It will ignore some of the memo_fields if they are None. It will not ignore these memo_fields: False, 0, [], {}, ()...

But in fact, I suggest you do something better, like:

```
any(memo_field[1][0] in row[9] for memo_field in memo_fields 
    if isinstance(memo_field, (tuple, list)) and 
       len(memo_field) > 1 and 
       isinstance(memo_field[1], (tuple, list)) and 
       len(memo_field[1]) > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could apply the [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) function to memo_fields to remove any None elements:

```
any(memo_field[1][0] in row[9] for memo_field in filter(None, memo_fields))
```

You should be aware that when using `None` as the first argument to filter, any values in `memo_fields` that are 'falsey' (i.e. [], {}, False, None) will be removed. In your case this is probably favorable, but worth being aware of.